# Multiplatform Cocos2d-x project

Tags: android, ios, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I want to start a new project from scratch and i want to release it in both android and ios platform.
i came across to cocos2d-x, but didnt understand the whole way.
can anybody guide me, is it possible to create c++ proj in cocos2d-x and convert the same proj to android and ios?

Comment: [This](http://paralaxer.com/cocos2d-x-project-setup/) was the best tutorial I was able to find.

Answer (score 2):

please refer to http://gameit.ro/2012/01/creating-an-iphone-and-android-cocos2d-x-hybrid-project-updated/

Comment: thanks a tone m.ding ... is there any such step by step tutorial for windows also? i m searching it since 3 days, but failed to get :(

Comment: I think it will be difficult. Since first, the iOS app can only be developed on Mac machine, second, Mac and Android are both kind of usisng Linux Kernel but windows is totally different. what I suggest is, if you got a windows machine, try to install Hackintoch.

Comment: Mac does not use a Linux kernel !

Comment: @Sucrenoir alright, it should be linux like Kernel. I know mac is build on Unix, and Linux is also starts from Unix. so they should be similar. :P

Comment: @chetanrane For Windows development, you can do the same by using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: FYI: I use VMWare Fusion on my Mac and then installed Windows so I can access both from Mac. Unfortunately a Hackintosh violates Apple terms and is much harder to set up than putting Windows on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

For multiplatform dev with cocos2d-x you may also consider using [CocosBuilder](http://cocosbuilder.com) v3.1 along with [javascript bindings](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/20/topics/9696) (see [this tutorial](http://2sa-studio.blogspot.fr/2013/04/setup-cross-platform-project-with.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Before cocos2d-x 2.1.2, you can still use templates in VS. However, you can only use python to  create project

1. Install python 2.7
2. Open command line in Windows
3. Go to your cocos2d-x-2.1.5\tools\project-creator folder
4. Run create_project.py. Usage:

> create_project.py -project YourProjectName -package com.example.PakcageName -language cpp

-language option:[cpp | lua | javascript]

Your project will be created in cocos2d-x-2.1.5\projects

- Windows：find the `proj.win32` , open ***.sln
- Android：find the `proj.android`, import into eclipse
- iOs：find the `proj.ios`...